# Spring MVC Hibernate Validator TypeMismatch Exception

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, spring-mvc-initbinders

I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate validator 4.2.0. have a ValidationMessages.properties on my class path in /WEB-INF/classes/ValidationMessages.properties:

```
typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer=Must specify an integer value.
typeMismatch.int=Invalid number entered
typeMismatch=Invalid type entered
```

This is made available as a bean in javaconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
...

@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasename("ValidationMessages");
    return resourceBundleMessageSource;
}
...
```

which is loading ValidationMessages.properties from the class path fine. My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class myController {
...

@InitBinder("myForm")
protected void initUserBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new CustomValidator());
}
...

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax/myRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CustomResponse ProcessAjaxRequest(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute final MyForm myForm,
        final BindingResult bindingResult)
                throws Exception {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new CustomResponse(bindingResult.getAllErrors());
    } else {
        ..
    }
}
...
```

And a custom validator:

```
public class CustomValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class c) {
    return MyForm.class.equals(c);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
..
```

Validation with my CustomValidator works fine (I insert the error messages manually, not using the message source), however for binding typeMismatch errors I get the exception:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'myField'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
```

rather than the code from ValidationMessages.properties, so it looks as though the DataBinder (?) is not using my messageSource.  I want the typeMismatch codes from my properties file rather than the exception message.  I have also tried with ResourceBundleMessageSource instead of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource but that didn't make any difference.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you get the error message? Is this work for you?

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
...

FieldError error = bindingResult.getFieldError("fieldName");
String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(error, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: I'm using constructor injection rather than Autowired, but I get:

Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property fieldName; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"

Comment: Looks like a problem with my bean definition?

Comment: Your bean definition seems fine. Do you use getDefaultMessage() to get the error message?

Comment: If you use getDefaultMessage(), you are not able to get your customized error message.  Seems that Spring default implementation ([DefaultBindingErrorProcessor](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/DefaultBindingErrorProcessor.java)) does not use MessageSource when it sets the default error message to the BindingResult object.

Comment: Yes, this was the cause - DefaultBindingErrorProcessor does not use MessageSource when it sets the error message for binding errors.  So I created my own custom DefaultBindingErrorProcessor with my MessageSource, and set WebDataBinder.setBindingErrorProcessor in my controller.